# Poetry forces use of old version of Mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-poetry

Poetry yields the following error on request to upgrade mypy:

```
<your-project> depends on both mypy (^0.812) and mypy (^0.761), version solving failed
```

mypy v0.761 considers type specification with bracket arguments (e.g., `Callable[[],Any]`) to be a syntax error.

This is problematic.

---

How does one force poetry to use the latest version of a package, or remove poetry's belief that the old version of a package is necessary? (by comparison, pip installs the latest version)

Comment: `poetry show --tree` should show you which package requires the old version of mypy.

Comment: @I0b0 that's odd.  I am seeing only `>=` rules for `mypy` from only one other package (`black`). I'll try removing `black`, but perhaps that is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into this strange issue in a Poetry project.

What ended up resolving it for me:

1. Delete my `poetry.lock` file
2. Remove both `black` and `mypy` from my `pyproject.toml`
3. Run `poetry update`
4. Run `poetry add mypy`
5. Run `poetry add black`

Now it's successfully running the latest versions of mypy and black that were "incompatible" before.